# Lockscreen pattern implementation in QML

Tags: qt, qml, lockscreen, unlock

I'm looking to implement a lockscreen pattern that can be used to uncover additional settings. For this, I have generated a 3x3 grid of `RoundButtons` using a `Repeater` as shown below:

```
Grid {
anchors.centerIn: parent
spacing: 10
columns: 3
rows: 3

    Repeater {
    id: rpt
    model: 9
    delegate: RoundButton {
            radius: Math.max(width, height) / 2
        }
    }
}
```

How can I detect which button the finger is being dragged over so I can add it to the pattern? I have looked at both `TapHandler` and `MouseArea` but I don't seem to understand what properties I can use to check whether a pressed finger is being dragged over the buttons.

Let me know if any additional info is missing that I should add. Thanks.